# Return function value from dll c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++

I have wrote dll in c++ and some function has vector type.
I want returrn those value in c#. this my code:
C++:

```
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)    vector< int>  convertA4(char  *filePath,  char *outPath) {}
```

c#:

```
    [DllImport("ConsoleApplication1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern List<int>  convertA4( string filePath, string outPath );
```

but when I run the app, this error has been showen:

```
Cannot marshal 'return value': Generic types cannot be marshaled.
```

Comment: the memory layout of a `vector<int>´ matches that of an array of integer, so the type should be an `int[]`, by value not by reference

Comment: Can you show me in code ??

Comment: see the duplicate: signature in c++ would be `int *convertA4(char *, char *)`, coming in as `int[] convertA4(string, string)`